# Running functions on page render

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a payment method to a checkout page that has no native support for it.

The button that links to the external web-page for payment requires an object with some parameters. I have managed to make functions that scrape the page and gather the required parameters and can make the object with no issues, but **ONLY** after the page has loaded and fully rendered (i.e. they work if I call the functions through the developer console on the browser).

The parameters that the button requires are the ***total*** of the purchase and an ***array of items*** that contains the quantity, price, etc. These are prepared by a main function that 2 calls helper functions and sets the other parameters for the object.

I would like for the main function to run (without it messing up the parameters) as soon as the page is loaded and cannot manage to get it working.

---

### Things I have tried and what has happened:

1. `window.onload` -> page breaks and does not load the text of the page correctly.
2. `$(window).on('load', foo())` -> object is created but the parameters scraped are full of jumble (i.e. NaN and very large numbers that do not appear on the page).
3. `setTimeout(foo(), 3000)` -> didn't work at all.
4. `Moving the js source call of the button in case the button code was running before the scraping` -> same results as #2

### Some details:

- The button is for ATH Movil. You can find the API [here](https://github.com/evertec/athmovil-javascript-api)
- I am relatively new to JavaScript
- The main function is:

```
    function updater(){
      var cartTotal = getOrderTotal()
      var itemCart = itemInhabiter()
    
      ATHM_Checkout.env = 'sandbox'
      ATHM_Checkout.publicToken = 'definitelynotarealtoken:D'
      ATHM_Checkout.theme = 'btn-dark'
      ATHM_Checkout.lang = 'es'
      ATHM_Checkout.total = cartTotal
      ATHM_Checkout.items = itemCart
    }
```

- The helper function that scrapes the total is:

```
    // Get the order total from the table (from what I have notice the total is always on the 4th child)
       function getOrderTotal(){
         var total = $('td:nth-child(4)').text()
    
         var parsedTotal = Number(total.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""))
    
         return parsedTotal
       }
```

- The helper function that scrapes the items is:

```
    // Fills an array with the details of the items in the order
       function itemInhabiter(){
    
         var items = new Array()
    
    // Avoids target taxes and fee rows (the last 6 rows)
         for (let i = 1; i <= $('tr').length - 6; i++) {
    
    // So that we can loop throught the rows
           var current = 'tr:nth-child(' + i + ')'
    
    // Contains the raw values of the current row in the checkout page
           var tempRawString = $(current).text()
    
    // The content that will fill the items array, its values will be replaced as the code goes through the checkout rows
           var content = new Object()
           content.description = "Generic description."
           content.tax = null
           content.metadata = null
    
    // Get the quantity and price of the current cart item
           var quantityNPrice = tempRawString.split(/[^0-9.-]+/g)
        
    // The quantity and price will always have the index of 1 & 2 respectively therefore set the values in content accordingly
              content.quantity = Number(quantityNPrice[1])
              content.price = Number(quantityNPrice[2])
    
    // Get the name of the current item
              var nameArray = tempRawString.split(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g)
              var itemName = nameArray.filter(Boolean).join(" ")
        
    // Set the name of the item
              content.name = itemName
              items.push(content)
            }
    
            return items
       }
```

---

### Current result:

```
   

     {
        env: "sandbox"
        items: Array(1)
        [
        0:
        description: "Generic description."
        metadata: null
        name: "translate SUBTOTAL parsePrice cart data subtotal Remove All Purpose Breadfruit Mix"
        price: 1.2345678910111213e+188
        quantity: NaN
        tax: null
        ]
    
        lang: "es"
        publicToken: "definitelynotarealtoken:D"
        theme: "btn-dark"
        total: NaN
     }
```

### Expected result:

*The one I get when I run the main function through the developer console*

```
   

     {
        env: "sandbox"
        items: Array(1)
        [
        0:
        description: "Generic Description."
        metadata: null
        name: "All Purpose Breadfruit Mix"
        price: 71.94
        quantity: 6
        tax: null
        ]
    
        lang: "es"
        publicToken: "definitelynotarealtoken:D"
        theme: "btn-dark"
        total: 90.61
     }
```

*This may not be the most efficient or right way at all to solve my problem, but it's all I could come up with. Any feedback is appreciated!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seemed to solve my problem was putting a small delay after `window.onload`, giving the files enough time to render and the script a good enough leeway to not overwrite or mess up any other functions that may be running when the page loads as well. *(Honestly other than the delay giving the page enough time to render, I have no idea why this worked)*

### Solution

`window.onload = setTimeout(function(){updater()}, 300)`

Answer (score 0):

to run something when the content is ready to be rendered in JQuery, you have to use `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready( ()=> {...} );
```

Comment: The same thing as ```$(window).on('load', foo())``` happens, the info gets jumbled and unusable